# ExpandableListView поиск по списку

Tags: java, android

Как реализовать поиск по списку `ExpandableListView`?

```
private String[] mGroupsArray = new String[] { "Зима", "Весна", "Лето", "Осень" };

private String[] mWinterMonthsArray = new String[] { "Декабрь", "Январь", "Февраль" };


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("Locale Date");

    Map<String, String> map;
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupDataList = new ArrayList<>();


    for (String group : mGroupsArray) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("groupName", group); 
        groupDataList.add(map);
    }

    // список атрибутов групп для чтения
    String groupFrom[] = new String[] { "groupName" };
    // список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты групп
    int groupTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    // создаем общую коллекцию для коллекций элементов
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> сhildDataList = new ArrayList<>();

    // в итоге получится сhildDataList = ArrayList<сhildDataItemList>

    // создаем коллекцию элементов для первой группы
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    // заполняем список атрибутов для каждого элемента
    for (String month : mWinterMonthsArray) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("monthName", month); // название месяца
        сhildDataItemList.add(map);
    }
    // добавляем в коллекцию коллекций
    сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);

    // список атрибутов элементов для чтения
    String childFrom[] = new String[] { "monthName" };
    // список ID view-элементов, в которые будет помещены атрибуты
    // элементов
    int childTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this, groupDataList,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, groupFrom,
            groupTo, сhildDataList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            childFrom, childTo);

    ExpandableListView expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListView);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Каким образом реализован адаптер для списка? Судя по всему поиск необходимо производить по массиву или контейнеру, который был передан в `ExpandableListView`.

UPDATE

Получи адаптер через метод `getExpandableListAdapter()`, и потом, пробегая по всем группам и подгруппам через методы `getGroup()` и `getChild()`, проверяй на свое условие, в зависимости от реализации механизма поиска.

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/expandablelistview.php
делал как тут , помогите с поиском

Comment: @Дмитрий Хм, что то у меня этот сайт не открывается... ) хотя обычно работает отлично

Comment: помоги с кодом у меня editText  в который надо вводить буквы по которым искать и ExpandableListView код которого выше , помоги полностью код написать

Comment: @Дмитрий после нажатия на поиск как должен вести себя список? оставлять только элементы, соответсвующие поиску?

Comment: да после нажатия на поиск должны оставаться только элементы, соответсвующие поиску

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно написать собственный адаптер , который будет реализовывать метод выборки только нужных значений из всего списка по строке для фильтрации ( фильтр по списку ) и в активити реализовать `SearchManager` ( а так же `SearchView` в разметке ) , который будет передавать в этот метод фильтрации в адаптере по какому , собственно , параметру ( строке ) сортировать. Метод фильтрации в адаптере будет формировать новый набор данных и обновлять список (`notifyDataSetChanged()`) , в котором будут только отсортированные значения /
Фактически нужно просто сформировать новые данные для списка на основе какого то ввода пользователя , отсеив из основных данных ненужное . Задача не сложная , но достаточно объемная по коду , поэтому предлагаю ознакомиться с [полноценным сэмплом реализации фильтра](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html)